# Closed-form expression for this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

A popular Internet image that has a double integral is:

[image]

However, even WolframAlpha cannot evaluate the integral:
$\int \int |x^{y^x} y^{x^y}| e^{xy} dy\;dx$. Is there a closed-form expression for the result? If not, is there one that does not involve the $e^{xy}$ term?

Comment: What is the decimal expansion?

Comment: Is the integral over some specific region? Otherwise what does the indefinite integral in two variables mean?